# Is this a good case for Multisite?

Tags: multisite

Okay, I'm sort of new to Multisite and I've seen a few cases that state one *should* use it, and similarly one *shouldn't* use it. I suppose I'm trying to figure out what's a Best Case scenario. I run several WordPress sites on my VPS, a couple using WooCommerce, some are just blogs. The case I'm trying to identify currently is for a client I'm hosting.

The client has 1 site currently but wants to move to a 3 site type approach.

- **Site 1**: Basic Overview of Services between the 2 sub brands, sharing some content from each if the following sites but not ALL
- **Site 2**: Vehicle Performance Products and Services
- **Site 3**: Vehicle Entertainment and Aesthetics

So each Site 2 & 3 may share information also, but not all of the pages.

So my question is, can a Multisite be the proper way to do this type of thing or should I be thinking of developing a custom solution entirely (which is the road I started down on first)?

Answer (score 1):

Use multisite for the following reasons:

1.) You can have the same login credentials for each site, so users that need to get into admin don't need to remember what site credentials to use.

2.) Depending on how your sites are setup a free plugin like "WP (three?) Broadcast" can let you copy pages/posts from one site to the other (including featured images)

3.) Site updates to plugins and themes all happen in one place at the network level

4.) Less space required on the file server because you have only 1 instance of wordpress installed; no duplicate files.

5.) Cheaper. Most themes and plugins you pay for are based on the number of wordpress installs you have. In your case it will always be 1 for this client. So basically you save on licensing most of the time. The exception is when licenses are based on "domain"

6.) Use Wordpress "MU Domain Mapping" plugin to make multisite management easier.

Additional Note: In multisite the sites will technically be seperated both the media library and on posts/pages. This is by design in wordpress, but as i stated there is the broadcast plugin that will let you share articles across domains and subdomains. With wordpress domain mapping plugin you can setup sites like site1.com, site2.com or foo.site1.com, bar.site1.com or you can mix and match as needed. So site1.com, foo.site1.com, site2.com, bar.site2.com, etc.

Comment: My experience: I run multisite on 3 related domains currently, and currently building to 12.